# Server locale C vs en_US.UTF-8

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, php, localization, i18n

I am considering to change all of my server locale to C by

```
"export LC_ALL=C"
```

Is it a common practice?

I am thinking will there be any side effect on a LAMP server, or should I just leave as using the default of "en_US.UTF-8"?

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish by changing this value?

Comment: To avoid issue like this: http://tdas.wordpress.com/2008/02/03/speed-up-grep/

Comment: That issue was reported over five years ago; have you been able to run a test with a more recent version of grep?  There's a decent chance that the performance is better, given that UTF-8 is becoming more and more prevalent.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to edit `/etc/default/locale` to set the locale as your export command will only affect the current environment. It will not affect already running programs.

The issue you had mentioned regarding grep was fixed a few years ago already:

```
fixed in grep 2.7, released Sep 20, 2010

In multibyte locales, regular expressions including backreferences
no longer exhibit quadratic complexity (i.e., they are orders
of magnitude faster). [bug present since multi-byte character set
support was introduced in 2.5.2]

In UTF-8 locales, regular expressions including "." can be orders
of magnitude faster.  For example, "grep ." is now twice as fast
as "grep -v ^$", instead of being immensely slower.  It remains
slow in other multibyte locales. [bug present since multi-byte
character set support was introduced in 2.5.2]
```

http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=6521